# creating unscrollble background image using html and css only

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

i am trying to make a web page which background is fixed (meaning width is 100% and height does not scroll ) but the main div of the page which contain all the content of the page is scroll-able in y direction. you can see the effect here   http://btemplates.com/2016/blogger-template-topgames/demo/. is it possible to achieve this effect using html and css only ? if not then how it can be done with javascript?

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets.

Comment: Can you edit your question and supply the code please?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily do that using a background image. If you inspect the page you can see how they did it.

CSS:

```
body {
   background: url('<<Your URL Here>>'), center top no-repeat fixed;
}

content-wrapper {
   width: 960px;
   margin: 46px auto 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
   <content-wrapper>
   </content-wrapper>
</body>
```

In the future, right-click the page and inspect the HTML and CSS and you should be able to figure most things out.